# Get farm status using CSOM PowerShell on premises

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, powershell

For complicated certificate/remoting reasons, we cannot use the PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell. I found a tutorial using CSOM objects, see example code:

```
Import-Module "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"
$site = "https://contoso.sharepoint.com"
$context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($site)
```

Is there a way to get useful farm or site information using this approach? Similar to `Get-SPFarm` or `Get-SPSite`. This is on-premises SharePoint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SharePoint CSOM is client side code, it can access only site collection or below level objects. It's impossible to get farm using CSOM.

To get a site imformation using csom, below is sample code:

```
Import-Module "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"
$siteurl = "https://contoso.sharepoint.com"
$context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($site)
$site=$context.site
$context.load($site)
$context.executequery()
write-host "URL:" $site.url  "CompatibilityLevel:"  $site.CompatibilityLevel
```